# How to get last week date range based on current date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code in crystal reports that gives me last week date range based on the current date.

First day of the week:

```
If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 2 Then
currentdate
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 3 Then
dateadd ("d",-1,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 4 Then
dateadd ("d",-2,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 5 Then
dateadd ("d",-3,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 6 Then
dateadd ("d",-4,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 7 Then
dateadd ("d",-5,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 1 Then
dateadd ("d",-6,currentdate)
```

Last day of week:

```
If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 2 Then
dateadd ("d",+6,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 3 Then
dateadd ("d",+5,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 4 Then
dateadd ("d",+4,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 5 Then
dateadd ("d",+3,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 6 Then
dateadd ("d",+2,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 7 Then
dateadd ("d",+1,currentdate)
Else If DayOfWeek(currentdate) = 1 then currentdate
```

How can I do the same in SQL using 2 variables to storage Monday(`startdate`) and Sunday(`enddate`)?

I found this `select datepart(dw,getdate()) --6` in this site, but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I generated some spaced out dates in the `parms` CTE then `SELECT` the `CurrentDate` from `parms`, the Sunday of the week prior to `CurrentDate` and the Saturday of the week prior to `CurrentDate`. I'm assuming that you want the dtate range to be Sunday - Saturday.

> Sunday - Saturday Ranges

```
;WITH parms (CurrentDate) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION 
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)

SELECT CurrentDate
     , LastWeekSunday   = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, CurrentDate) - 1, 0))
     , LastWeekSaturday = DATEADD(dd,  5, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, CurrentDate) - 1, 0))
FROM parms
```

> Monday to Sunday Ranges

```
;WITH parms (CurrentDate) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION 
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)

SELECT CurrentDate
     , LastWeekMonday   = DATEADD(dd,  0, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CurrentDate)) - 1, 0))
     , LastWeekSunday   = DATEADD(dd,  6, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CurrentDate)) - 1, 0))
FROM parms
```

> If you just want the prior week's Monday to the prior week's Sunday from today rather than from a column of dates you can use this

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     , LastWeekSunday   = DATEADD(dd,  0, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - 1, 0))
     , LastWeekSaturday = DATEADD(dd,  6, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - 1, 0))
```

Comment: I need Monday - Sunday

Comment: @cojimarmiami, the numbers are a little different for Monday to Sunday ranges. I added the code to use for Monday - Sunday but left the Sunday - Saturday code and labeled both.

Comment: could you please explain me the logic behind that statement because when I run it I get 6 different  LastWeekMonday   and the same for LastWeekSunday

Comment: The `parms` CTE is just there to generate a couple of dates (six rows actually). That's why you are getting six rows of results. You would just use the `SELECT` statement at the end and replace "parms" with your actual table name.

Comment: @cojimarmiami, My code also assumes you are selecting from a date column in a table called CurrentDate. I added a third section to get the prior week's date range using just today's date.

Answer (score 10):

This solution is tested and works. I am getting the previous week's Monday and Sunday as upper and lower bounds.

```
SELECT
    -- 17530101 or 1753-01-01 is the minimum date in SQL Server
    DATEADD(dd, ((DATEDIFF(dd, '17530101', GETDATE()) / 7) * 7) - 7, '17530101') AS [LowerLimit], -- Last Week's Monday
    DATEADD(dd, ((DATEDIFF(dd, '17530101', GETDATE()) / 7) * 7) - 1, '17530101') AS [UpperLimit] -- Last Week's Sunday.
```

Which can be used like this in a real world query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    SomeTable.[Date] >= DATEADD(dd, ((DATEDIFF(dd, '17530101', GETDATE()) / 7) * 7) - 7, '17530101') AND
    SomeTable.[Date] <= DATEADD(dd, ((DATEDIFF(dd, '17530101', GETDATE()) / 7) * 7) - 1, '17530101')
```

Here are some tests:

**1. Leap Year**

Current Date: `2016-02-29 00:00:00.000`

Results:

```
LowerLimit                 UpperLimit
2016-02-22 00:00:00.000    2016-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

**2. Last Week was in different year**

Current Date: `2016-01-06 00:00:00.000`

```
LowerLimit                 UpperLimit
2015-12-28 00:00:00.000    2016-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

**3. Lower limit in previous month and upper limit in current month**

Current Date: `2016-05-04 00:00:00.000`

```
LowerLimit                 UpperLimit
2016-04-25 00:00:00.000    2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

**4. Current Date is Sunday**

Current Date: `2016-05-08 00:00:00.000`

```
LowerLimit                 UpperLimit
2016-04-25 00:00:00.000    2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 3):

Bill's code worked well, but I needed to make a slight edit if I wanted to get last Sunday to Saturday based on today's date.

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
LastWeekSunday   = DATEADD(dd,  -1, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - (case datename(weekday,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) when 'Sunday' then 0 else 1 end), 0)), 
LastWeekSaturday = DATEADD(dd,  5, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - (case datename(weekday,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) when 'Sunday' then 0 else 1 end), 0))
```

Rgds - Matt

Answer (score 2):

For everything date and date interval related, I'd almost always recommend using a calendar table. A table with columns representing date, week, month, year, day of week, hiliday, weekand, etc, prepopulated as needed and indexed on every column. It's only 365 rows per year.

```
select min(date), max(date)
from calendar
where week = datepart(week, getdate() - 7)
and year = datepart(year, getdate() - 7)
```

Comment: what happen is that code will be included in a SP that will be used in crystal reports in an auto delivery report.

Answer (score 0):

A shortened version concise syntax

---

last week, in my vision is the prev adjacent week, so if Im doing report during the week days, I want to receive dates of previous adjacent week Monday to Sunday.

- prev Monday is DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -(5 + dayofweek(CURDATE())) DAY)
- prev Sunday is DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -(dayofweek(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY)
- then to take the report from the table need just to integrate those two in SELECT statement

`select * from XXX where DateCol between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -(5 + dayofweek(CURDATE())) DAY) and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -(dayofweek(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY) order by DateCol`

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party, but wanted to add a simpler way that works for me in SQL Server (when the other examples did not).

```
select * from table
```

-- this is for the previous week:

```
where (datefield >= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) and datefield < DATEADD(dd,  6, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)))
```

-- alternatively, this is for a rolling 7 days:

```
and DATEDIFF(day, datefield, GETDATE()) between 0 and 7
```